# Functions of Independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Why is it that if for **independent** random variables $X_i \ni i $ is finite, then the expectation of:

$$E\bigg[Z^{\sum_i X_i}\bigg] = \Pi_i \ E\bigg[Z^{X_i}\bigg]$$

Would this be true for the expectation of any **function** of $X_i$?
And what conditions must be satisfied for this to be true? i.e. continuity etc...

So My problem is that $X_i$ are independent. Not the **functions** of them. Is there a theorem or property that says that joint functions of independent variables equal to the product of the partials in case of independent r.v. If so, what conditions do we put on the functions? Thanks

Comment: I know that the joint CDFs and PDFs equal the product of the partials, but for other joint **functions** to equal the product of the partials, do they have to be CDFs?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something subtle here, but $Z^{x_1+x_2}=Z^{x_1}Z^{x_2}$.  So it's just a rearrangement, writing the Z factor as a multiplication instead of a sum in the exponent. If they are independent, then $$E[Z^{x_1}Z^{x_2}...]=E[Z^{x_1}]\cdot E[Z^{x_2}]...$$which is sort of the definition of independence (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory).

Comment: My problem is that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent. Not the **function** of them. Is there a theorem or property that says functions of independent variables are in fact independent. If so, what conditions do we put on the functions? Thanks

Comment: I know that the joint CDFs and PDFs equal the product of the partials, but for other joint **functions** to equal the product of the partials, do they have to be CDFs?

Comment: check the Wikipedia page. For general functions, no; for expectation, yes (that is what I meant when I said it is almost the definition of independence).